# XAML Scroll intoView wont work in async function?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, code-behind, autoscroll

im using the following code to display some tweets in a ListView.
I'm inserting every tweet at position index = 0 to display the latest tweet at the bottom of the listView (x:name = standardTweetBox).

```
 private async void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
        {[...]

        if (searchResponse != null && searchResponse.Statuses != null)
        {
            foreach (Status status in searchResponse.Statuses)
            {
                Tweet tweet = new Tweet(status.User.ScreenNameResponse, status.User.ProfileImageUrl, status.Text, status.CreatedAt.ToString());

                standardTweetBox.Items.Insert(0, tweet);

            }
        }
```

Usually the following code should work to focus at the latest tweet at the bottom of the listView

```
standardTweetBox.ScrollIntoView(standardTweetBox.Items[standardTweetBox.Items.Count - 1]);
```

I was succesfull to implement this line of code at a different part of the code. Of course using the event TextBox_Change doesnt make any sense, but it proves to code to be working.

```
    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        standardTweetBox.ScrollIntoView(standardTweetBox.Items[standardTweetBox.Items.Count-1]);
    }
```

Is it possible that this line of code just doenst work properly in an async function?

Here is my XAML code if needed:

```
  <ListView Grid.Row="1"        
            x:Name = "standardTweetBox"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TweetBox}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
            >
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
    <!--</ScrollViewer>-->
    <TextBox  Grid.Row="2" Height="150" Width="380" Text="{Binding Title}" Background="#99FFFFFF" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
```

Let me know if you need any further information.

Cheers

Comment: Try to do it in UI thread: `Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => standardTweetBox.ScrollIntoView(standardTweetBox.Items[standardTweetBox.Items.Count - 1]));`

Comment: Nope. Doesnt Help. Added the following: 
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => standardTweetBox.ScrollIntoView(standardTweetBox.Items[standardTweetBox.Items.Co‌​unt - 1]));